# nginx - Subdomain as querystring parameter?

Tags: nginx, multi-tenant

I have a simple, single-page web application which accepts a query string parameter, `name`. This web application currently prints the parameter's value; so, the page at `http://example.com/app/?name=person1` displays the text `person1`.

I would like to use nginx to internally route requests to `http://person1.example.com/` to `http://example.com/app/?name=person1` so that the same text is retrieved.

Ideally, I would also like to make the name of the subdomain available to either a PHP or a Node.js process in order to reuse the same application files across different subdomains, allowing the application itself to handle requests internally based on whichever URL the client is currently accessing.

However, I would like to do this dynamically- without setting up a new virtual host for every subdomain.

Can this be done with dynamic virtual hosts on nginx, and if so, how?
Can anyone point me in the right direction, or help to explain what I'm struggling to understand?

Additionally, is there a better alternative to what I am attempting to do?

Comment: Does this all happen on the same server?

Comment: @ColeTierney I should have specified- yes, I would like to run nginx alongside PHP-FPM or Node.js on the same machine and accomplish this. Somehow. I just don't know how I might approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an external redirect is alright, I would try something like the following:

```
map $host $subdomain {
    ~^(?<sub>.+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ $sub;
}

server {
    listen  80  default_server;
    server_name _;

    if ($subdomain) {
        return 301 http://example.com/app/?name=$subdomain;
    }
}
```

If an internal redirect is required, a rewrite or proxy_pass may be necessary.

Comment: This does look promising! What is `map`, and what's happening there? There are some things in that regular expression that I can't make heads or tails of, like the `<sub>` bit up front.

Comment: The `map` directive is an efficient place to use regex to define a variable. The author, Igor Sysoev, explains why [over here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I). The `<sub>` expression captures a subdomain if present in the `$host` variable and returns it as the variable `$subdomain`. The regex could be written as
`~^(?<sub>.+)\.example\.com$`.

Comment: Ack! I got caught up in schoolwork and forgot to accept your answer. My apologies, and thanks again for the help! I had no idea what `map` was, but it's been super useful.

Comment: Thats ok Conner! I enjoy helping when I can. What goes around comes around.