# Create subdomain masking for each user in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to add subdomain URL for each user.

For eg: if my site has a user name as John then the URL which he will be sharing with his users is `http://john.example.com` and this should open the home page for my site  `http://example.com`.

My site is in WordPress and hosted over WP Engine server.
I have enabled the wildcard domain mapping from WP Engine also added respective A records.

Now the issue is, if I try to hit `http://john.example.com` WordPress redirects me to `http://example.com`.

Instead I want it to stay and send a request like `http://john.example.com` => `http://example.com?user=john`.

Do I need to write any htaccess/nginx rule for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831742/nginx-subdomain-as-querystring-parameter